# Trying to use data from coco-ssd to draw a bounding box

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, dom, image-recognition, tensorflow.js

I have been recently inquiring about image recognition and found that JavaScript had an easy to use and beginner friendly way to do this using tensorflow.js. I managed to use the exemplar code for an interesting model I found called coco-ssd. It works really well and returns the data for the predictions (It returns an array of the four points enclosing the subject) and everything but now I have the issue of using it. For the purposes I want I would like to be able to draw a bounding box around the person in frame or at the very least know the coordinates in pixels of the original image (resizing has been a real issue). I don't know what to do because all the tutorials I have seen use the `<canvas>` element. When I try to use this the canvas never seems to display properly. Here is the code (I moved the code from a separate file into the script tags for convenience):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"> </script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd"> </script>
<!-- replace 'Lenin.jpg' with a local file in the same folder as this program -->
<img id="img" src="Lenin.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<script>


  const img = document.getElementById('img');

  cocoSsd.load().then(model => {
    model.detect(img).then(predictions => {
      console.log('Predictions: ', predictions);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you post a codeSandbox of this?

Comment: Are you trying to make something like [this](https://aicamcam.github.io/)?

Comment: Sorry, what I was trying to do was really actually turn the returned coordinates into pixel coordinates so I know exactly where in the image the box is.